# Google Analytics Event tracking for Goals

Tags: google-analytics, event-tracking

I am having an issue in using the Google Goals for my My Event Tracking. I have added Google even tracking code to my web page. However, I cannot check for any conversions in my Google Goals but the event result can be shown in the Google Analytic --> Behavior --> Events Overview.

My Code is below

```
`     <script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-87810245-1', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
      <script>

$('#contact-form').on('submit', function(event) {
  // Prevent the browser's default form submission action.
  event.preventDefault();

  ga('send', 'event', {
    eventCategory: 'Contact',
    eventAction: 'Information Request',
    eventLabel: 'Contact Form',
    hitCallback: function() {
      $('contact-form').trigger('submit');
    }
  });
});

      </script>`
```

Code for my Submit Button:

```
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Validate and Submit" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'form', 'submit', 'order sent', 10);"/>
```

My Google Goals:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/blJjF.png)[image]

Google Analytics Events Overview: 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you've got two events going on, one for the click of the submit button (to track intent perhaps) and one for the form submission itself. Your goal is configured to expect a value `Greater than` 10, but your form submission event is not passing a value in. You should either add a value (greater than 10), or remove the value from the goal configuration. Also your screenshot shows likely just the click event (since there's a value of 10 associated with it), but you'd probably be more interested in the actual submissions themselves.